# NK2 files doesn't keep the email addresses in memory

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, contacts

When I send an email to someone outside the firm, when I only type the first letters of its name (Contact), I get the auto-suggest of the "Already-sent" users.

So now, since a few days, the emails are not kept in memory by Outlook (NK2 file). I see that that file is only 2kb and on my old machine, it's almost 200kb (So a lot more email addresses kept in memory)

Should I just rebuilt the Outlook profile or the whole Windows Profile? A simple Outlook reinstall or to build a new PC?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just changed computers? Copy the .NK2 file from the old system and overwrite the file on the new system.

Comment: It's a new PC in deed but 1 month old. I don't have the old one anymore. But the things is that I sent email to people so the email addresses must have been saved but after a reboot, the next day, some of them are gone.